# Hidding a row in jquery Grid

Tags: jquery

jQuery grid row hide using row index

I have already tried this example

```
window.jQuery("#row_with_row_id","#grid name"). style({display:"none"})
```

but it is not working

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the space between the methods and change the code as:

```
$("#row_with_row_id, #grid name").css({
  'display': 'none'
});
```

And also, why are you using `window.jQuery()`? Just use `jQuery()` or `$()` to select the elements.

The simpler way is:

```
$('#row_with_row_id').hide();
$('#grid name').hide();
```

And just let the jQuery handle it. jQuery will add `display: none` to the style attribute of the element's itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `css()` in jQuery instead of `style()`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("#row_with_row_id,#grid name").css({
         'display':'none'
    }); 
});
```

[**Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/css/)